# On Elasticsearch, how to aggregate based on the number of items in a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

On Elasticsearch I have a field named `Itinerary` that can contain multiple values (from 1 up to 6), for example in the picture below there's 2 items in the field.

```
"Itinerary": [
              {
                "Carrier": "LH",
                "Departure": "2021-07-04T06:55:00Z",
                "Number": "1493",
                "Arrival": "2021-07-04T08:40:00Z",
              },
              {
                "Carrier": "LH",
                "Departure": "2021-07-04T13:30:00Z",
                "Number": "422",
                "Arrival": "2021-07-04T16:05:00Z",
                }
              }
]
```

Is there a way I can aggregate based on the number of items in the field? Having something like:

```
1 item : 2
2 item : 4
...
```

Comment: Do you want to find count of items in each Itinerary?

Comment: Yeah, each entry has an Itinerary field, and the field can have up to 6 items (in the above pic there's 2), I want to aggregate in a way that would search through the Itinerary fields of all entries and separate/aggregate them based on the number of items in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itinerary type needs to be define as nested type

```
"Itinerary":
{
  "type": "nested"
}
```

1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to group on a field. You can use script to get count of array or better introduce a field which has count of array
2. [Top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get documents under that group

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['Itinerary.Carrier.keyword'].length"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "NAME" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index8",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "8OW1lnsBRh1xpgSkIOlq",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Itinerary" : [
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T06:55:00Z",
                        "Number" : "1493",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T08:40:00Z"
                      },
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T13:30:00Z",
                        "Number" : "422",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T16:05:00Z"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index8",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "8uW6lnsBRh1xpgSkAun1",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Itinerary" : [
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH2",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T06:55:00Z",
                        "Number" : "14931",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T08:40:00Z"
                      },
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH2",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T13:30:00Z",
                        "Number" : "4221",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T16:05:00Z"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 3,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "NAME" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index8",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "8eW1lnsBRh1xpgSkdukQ",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "Itinerary" : [
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH1",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T06:55:00Z",
                        "Number" : "14931",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T08:40:00Z"
                      },
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH1",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T13:30:00Z",
                        "Number" : "4221",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T16:05:00Z"
                      },
                      {
                        "Carrier" : "LH1",
                        "Departure" : "2021-07-04T13:30:00Z",
                        "Number" : "3221",
                        "Arrival" : "2021-07-04T16:05:00Z"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```